# EMC and Control Area Networks

Tags: emc, can, bus, standard, test

With radiated EMI tests, do we need to take into account the communication cabling and its influence on EMI?

I can't seem to find one standard that describes how CAN busses should be configured in EMI testing.

Comment: "CAN busses" can be anything. A multi-node system sprawling across a whole factory or a small point-to-point system constrained to less than a meter of cabling in some mobile application. Baud rates can be anything from 10kbps to 1Mbps (not taking CAN FD etc in account). Cables could be plain, twisted pair and/or shielded. And so on - without specifics you can't do anything. There won't be a standard describing how long a rope is nor will there be one describing how a CAN bus should be configured in regards to EMC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. How depends on the standard. CISPR22 for example uses AMNs (Artificial Mains Network) and ISNs (Impedance Stabilization Network) for terminating and coupling mains and telecommunication lines respectively.  CANbus would be an example of the latter.

CANbus in an office setting might conceivably be subject to CISPR22 ("Limits and Methods of Measurement of Radio Disturbance Characteristics; Part 7: Information Technology Equipment").  Or for industrial, CISPR11 ("Part 4: Industrial, Scientific and Medical (ISM) Radio-Frequency Equipment").  Or the US equivalents are, roughly speaking, FCC Parts 15 and 18, respectively.  Still others apply for other settings, e.g. automotive, railway, etc., not to mention other jurisdictions.

If just to get a representative idea of how things are set up, you can look up any of these standards; the specifics do vary between them, so you will want to also get the proper standard for whatever market(s) your product is targeted at.